Thousands of Linux distros that have an UI offer a Terminal going on a shell. But on Android it seems that such Terminal cannot exist. Why?
My question will depict that I can't figure the real distance between an Android operating system and a Linux distro.
When I try most distros that have an UI, from the earliest to the most recent one, the simplest to the one for experts, all are offering a shell. sh, bash, etc. If I try one on distrosea or another web site of that kind, I'm sure to have at least this feature, to try my ls or pwd command...
But there's nothing like that on my Android phone.
It's not the purpose of a smartphone to offer a terminal opening on a shell prompt, that's true. But for years that they exist, I guess some users would have thought about it.
But I never seen a terminal on a smartphone... If no place nowhere offers me to install one, it's surely that it's impossible.
And I'm asking myself: if for thousands of distros having an UI a terminal application opening to a shell is available, why can such terminal absolutely not exist in an Android Operating System, if is it of Linux kind? What is preventing it?

Epilog: I've lost reputation points but I've gained an useful knowledge. I was sure, not having searched efficiently, that they were no way to access to a shell on an Android phone.
And I've learned the contrary. I'm happy. Thanks!

termux works really well

It is hard to answer the question why a thing cannot exist when that thing clearly exists.

If you're asking why Google hasn't created one by default, they probably never felt the need for one, until recently: https://www.androidauthority.com/android-linux-terminal-app-3489887/

I’m voting to close this question because even if such a limitation did exist, it would be related to non-Unix parts of Android.

I've had a terminal on my Android since the very first Android phone I ever got. Why are you saying you can't? Here are some random ones I found simply by searching for "Google play terminal emulator": https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ddm.qute, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sw.programme.te, here's a site offering the classic "Best X" list: https://www.androidauthority.com/best-terminal-emulators-android-1201492/. There really isn't any lack of such tools.

Note to close voters: I don't see how this is off topic. Yes, it shows a lack of research, yes the premise is mistaken, but that's a reason to downvote, not close. We don't close questions for lack of research, we close them for being off topic.

@terdon "even if such a limitation did exist, it would be related to non-Unix parts of Android"

Probably I can not say it as an answer, but yes as a comment. While Google imported Linux into android, it very clearly, intentionally, did from the very beginning to remove from it everything what makes Linux good. If you worked by large companies a lot, I think one can feel: it is only some unintended side effect or intentional. Yes Google wanted to make Android intentionally so bad for the Linuxers as possible, it is a very intentional policy by them. This is why it has no embedded terminal.

Nothing prevents terminal emulators on Android. The most famous one is probably Termux but it’s not the only one.

Google Play Store policies make it complicated to publish functional terminal emulators there, other than terminal emulators designed solely to access remote systems. See the Termux documentation for a brief summary.
